# OTHERWISE meaning in "Pay owner twice the rental to which he/she is otherwise entitled"

Tags: word-meaning

In these sentences

> Advance token to the nearest Railroad and pay owner twice the rental to which he/she {he} is **otherwise** entitled. If Railroad is unowned, you may buy it from the Bank

General meaning is   'pay owner twice the rental amount which he/she is entitled to ' 
  But what is the meaning of **otherwise** in here and will anything significant happen if we remove it ?
Thank you for answering!

Comment: This looks like a sentence drawn without any context from a lease agreement. I am guessing that it comes from a section of such an agreement dealing with breach or cure or both. Presumably there was an earlier sentence specifying certain conditions, and this sentence covers all other conditions. Question as posed is terrible and should be closed unless it is edited to provide context.

Comment: Advance token to the nearest Railroad and pay owner twice the rental to which he/she {he} is otherwise entitled. If Railroad is unowned, you may buy it from the Bank. I've seen this in a board game called **Monopoly**

Comment: Yes, it's Monopoly or some knock-off of it. The owner must be paid $50.00. Otherwise, he is entitled to $25.00. Otherwise here means: if you were not paying him double.

Comment: This payment is made under the special circumstances of your having drawn a card from the deck.  **otherwise** refers to the rental due when landing on that railroad tile as part of a *normal* roll of the dice, that is, not under these special circumstances.

Comment: *Otherwise* means what it usually means, which any dictionary will tell you.

Comment: @JeffMorrow  You must not play a lot of Monopoly.  I recognized it right off.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that under normal circumstances there is some defined rent you must pay if your token lands on a railroad square, but if you must go to a railroad square under the circumstances indicated, you must pay double rent.

Comment: It's totaly right but , what is the meaning of **otherwise**in here?

Comment: I though I explained that in my previous comment. It means **in any circumstances other than those currently being discussed.**